# Creating friendly urls using .htaccess that is located in a subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder structure like so

```
root/folder1/folder2/2023/
```

This works fine if I put the following `.htaccess` file in my root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/foo?$ folder1/folder2/$1/foo.php [NC,L]
```

`https://example.com/folder1/folder2/2023/foo.php` Original url

`https://example.com/2023/foo` New url

**Subfolder2**

How do I get the same URL above if I put my `.htaccess` file in `folder2`

This works if I use the `RewriteRule` below but I don't want `/folder1/folder2/` in my URL `https://example.com/folder1/folder2/2023/foo`

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/foo$ $1/foo.php [NC,L]
```

Is this possible or should I just keep my `.htaccess` in my root directory.

Comment: _"Is this possible"_ - no. If you were to put the .htaccess into `/folder1/folder2/`, then it won't be read in the first place, when you request `/2023/foo`. The web server has no reason to go look _in_ `/folder1/folder2/`, based on that requested URL.

Comment: @CBroe Might as well put that as an answer. (Or close/delete the question.)

Comment: A quick read of the manual would be handy here... "The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof." https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: `^(\d{4})/foo?$` - Why the `?`?

Comment: That was a typo I have removed it now

Comment: You got no help? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

in the last folder put this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ foo.php?id=$1
```

It worked at least for me